# How to delete Shared Preferences file after migrating it to DataStore Preferences?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I migrate the shared preferences to data store migration using   :

```
val data Store = getImAppContext().createDataStore(
            name = OTP_PREFERENCES,
            migrations = listOf(
                SharedPreferencesMigration(
                    getImAppContext(),
                    OTP_PREFERENCES
                )
            )
        )
```

but how to delete shared preferences after successful migration so that if i relaunch the app i should access all data from data store preferences .Shared preferences should not get migrating again after relaunching.

Comment: `preferenceEditor.clear();` will remove all data from your Shared preferences.call this `preferenceEditor.apply();` after clear.

Comment: i am migrating from shared preferences to datastore preferences.So i can not use this editor

Comment: then use `yourSharedPref.getAll().clear();` for deleting Shared Preferences.